# wordpress - how to access and edit index.php file

Tags: wordpress, indexing

Is there a way to edit the index.php file in wordpress?

Around the web i found a lot of post saying to go to appearance -> editor,

but I can't find this menu... maybe this feature was removed...

So how can I do it?

Comment: do you want to edit the theme file?

Comment: Yes , you can modify from appearance -> editor, At right side you will get index.php , click on that file name so it will open in editor to modify.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can edit your PHP files.

**Method 1: Edit the file in your Installation Directory on the Web Server**
(this is what Anoop Asok is talking about)

> Go to WordPress Installation directory. Follow the path wp-content >
>   themes. Open your theme folder. In that you can see index.php file.
>   Edit it and save.

**Method 2: Edit the file from the WP Dashboard**
(This is easier and is what you were trying to do but that file isn't always made available by your theme)

- Download, install, and activate the Synchi plugin (this is an awesome IDE and one of its nice features is that it will allow you advanced theme editing)
- Go to Appearance > Editor . Now you will see the -themes- window on the right and you will have full access to all your theme files.
- Double-click your theme and drill down until you find your file you want to edit

**NOTE!** You should avoid editing your theme files because they might be over-written next time you update your theme. [Make a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and put a copy of index.php in there and work off that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please do this.

Go to WordPress Installation directory.
Follow the path `wp-content` > `themes`.
Open your theme folder.
In that you can see `index.php` file.
Edit it and save.